# Should I create Two Angular projects for Admin and Users?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-template

I'm working on Spring boot Application for the back-end and angular 6 for the front-end. I'm going to include two html templates in angular, the first one is for the Administration and the second One for the users. So, should I create two Angular projects or only one project and contains two big components for the admin and the users?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you have many shared pages/components i would setup a single project with a good module separation and guard setup.

If that's not the case you can do whatever you prefer

Comment: Creating multiple apps in one project could it be a solution for this problem ?

Comment: For what i can tell by personal experience, in my company i have a similar structure and the decision was to have a single project and it works great