# Should I include my admin page into the angular project or should i create a seperate one?

Tags: angular, security, project-structure

Hey i'm working on a frontend for my SpringBoot Application.
I'm just starting to learn Angular.
I'm not sure if there is a security issue if i create my admin-page in the same project.

Admin- and User-Page would share a lot of code but admin operations (or even data) shouldn't be accessable for anybody else.

What i've found so far:
[Should I create Two Angular projects for Admin and Users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674332/should-i-create-two-angular-projects-for-admin-and-users)

So creating one Angular project with two modules should be the way to go right?
But how do i approach that?
Or can i just build a single one module project with authentification and admin/user roles?
What would be best practice?

Thank you

Comment: There's no security issues in keeping them in the same project. Don't depend on preventing resources from loading via guards or hiding urls as a method of security though, always secure your endpoints with auth if you need to keep data secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently developed a project that has a user facing set of pages and an admin set of pages.

The way I have structured my project is roughly like the following:

```
|- AppModule
|-- app components
|-- app services
|-- app routing
|
|- SharedModule
|-- components
|
|- AdminModule
|-- admin components
|-- admin services
|-- admin routing
```

Both AppModule and AdminModule import SharedModule. AdminModule is lazy loaded from my root admin path in AppRouting like this:

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  canLoad: [AdminGuardService],
  loadChildren: () => import('../modules/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
}
```

Where AdminGuardService is a route guard that checks if the current user has admin access.

The benefit of a lazy loaded module is that it is compiled separately from AppModule, and is only loaded by the browser when my admin path is hit. I keep all of my admin-specific http calls in my admin services, so they never make it into my main app bundle.

From a security perspective, there's nothing to stop non-admin users guessing your admin urls regardless of whether it's in the same project or a different project. All of my backend authorization is done by my API. So if a non-admin user guesses an admin url, they will get a 401 and I will redirect them back to the main app.